# Rule swing with spring experiment: how can I modify it?

Tags: experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

[image]

Basically I want to replicate this experiment (https://youtu.be/GqPGbHq2fxU). It's a ruler oscillating with one fixed end and one end attached to a spring. In my previous experiment, I used a short spirng (didn't measure the spring constant which I regret a lot). The oscillation was so fast, period of which was around  $0.10 \ s$. I had to record it and count the number of frames to determine the period. What's more, the  oscillation was very unstable (dk whether this is the right word), meaning that it was swinging in every direction.

So I want to know if there is any way I can modify my experiment and make it as smooth as in the video?

I don't have a ruler with holes in it, so I stuck a piece of tape on it and used a thread through the tape, to hang the ruler to the clamp. I suspect it contributed to the instability, but can't find any other ways to hang it. Are there methods I can hang it with little friction?

If you want to have further discussion about the experiment, feel free to comment!

I would really appreciate your help! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not bore a hole or two in the ruler? Or use a cheap wooden strip, you don't need a ruler since you can measure the distances. If you don't use the hole, it may always swing in more directions. Use  for the spring: attach first a weight comparable to the ruler or strip and measure the frequency, if it is slow enough it is slow enough for your experiment, otherwise your spring is too strong.